# DateTime::createFromFormat not working as expected

Tags: php, datetime

Running PHP 5.3.28

I have a particular date getting returned as a string that strtotime is choking on, so I thought to try out DateTime::createFromFormat(), however despite best efforts getting errors.

```
<?php

$freshdate = '09/07/2015 (Mon)';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y (D)", $freshdate);
if (!$date) {
  var_dump('error', DateTime::getLastErrors());
}
```

Result is:

```
array (size=4)
  'warning_count' => int 0
  'warnings' => array (size=0)
  'error_count' => int 2
  'errors' => array (size=2)
      12 => string 'A textual day could not be found' (length=32)
      16 => string 'Data missing' (length=12)
```

Comment: [I cannot reproduce this](https://eval.in/431992)

Comment: @JohnConde The error can only be reproduced with PHP 5.3.0 - 5.4.19, 5.5.0 - 5.5.3 https://3v4l.org/tf473

Comment: It's reproducible in PHP 5.3 - try on http://phptester.net/

Comment: Looks like a version specific bug. Upgrading might be the only solution.

Comment: Why don't you just remove the `(Mon)` from the string and just parse the `m/d/Y` part?

Comment: @JohnConde Let's say, since PHP 5.3 is just [dead](http://php.net/supported-versions.php) upgrading would be the smartest solution

Comment: From the changelog for 5.4.20: - Fixed [bug #65554](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65554) (createFromFormat broken when weekday name is followed by some delimiters)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is bug in [PHP#65554](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65554):

> createFromFormat fails when in the format D or l is followed by separators that 
>   are not space or comma.

How to fix? Change your format or upgrade your PHP version.

Comment: Given that PHP 5.4 is EOL in just two days, the recommendation to upgrade is a good one

Answer (score 3):

From the changelog for 5.4.20: - Fixed [bug #65554](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=65554) (createFromFormat broken when weekday name is followed by some delimiters)

So the problem is the trailing `)` after the day name

You can workround it by trimming that trailing `)`:

```
$freshdate = '09/07/2015 (Mon)';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y (D", rtrim($freshdate, ')'));
if (!$date) {
  var_dump('error', DateTime::getLastErrors());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Use this-**

```
<?php

$freshdate = '09/07/2015 (Mon)';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("m/d/Y (D)", $freshdate);
echo $date->format('m/d/Y (D)');
```

Comment: You should add few words of explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, convert it to a unix timestamp:

```
$freshdate = explode('/', '09/07/2015 (Mon)');
$year = explode(' ', $freshdate[2]);
$unix_date = mktime(0,0,0,$freshdate[0],$freshdate[1],$year[0]);
```

Might not be the best answer, but its definitely AN answer :)